# OrderBy with linked database tables in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table with products, one with categories and one linking the products to multiple categories. All with correct foreign keys linking them together. When the user is in a category, the products within this category are selected using the `ProductToCategory` model.

But what I would like is to find an easy way, without looping through the output of linked products to this category to sort the products by name.

My database layout:

```
products
    id: 1; name: testing 123
    id: 2; name: testing 345
    id: 3; name: testing 567

product_categories
    id: 1; name: cat one
    id: 2; name: cat two
    id: 3; name: cat three

product_to_categories
    id: 1; product_id: 1; product_category_id: 1
    id: 2; product_id: 1; product_category_id: 2
    id: 3; product_id: 2; product_category_id: 1
    id: 4; product_id: 3; product_category_id: 1
    id: 5; product_id: 3; product_category_id: 2
    id: 6; product_id: 3; product_category_id: 3
```

In my ProductCategory Model I have:

```
public function ProductToCategory() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductToCategory');
}
```

In my ProductToCategory model I have:

```
public function Product() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product', 'product_id');
}
```

In the controller I have:

```
$linked_products = $category->ProductToCategory()->get();
foreach($linked_products as $linked_product) {
    if($linked_product->Product->is_active == 1) {
        $array[$linked_product->product_id] = $linked_product->Product);
    }

}
```

This gives me with `$linked_product->Product` the product info I need.

But using the Eloquent approach in the models I want to order the products by name before giving me the query result.

How do I go about that?

Comment: What is ProductToCategory? Why don't you use many-to-many with belongsToMany?

Comment: ProductToCategory is a table where one product can be linked into multiple categories. So you have for example product_id 1 is in the database as `product_id 1; category_id 1;` and `product_id 1; category_id 2;`. So I do a query with the category_id to get all products in this category. It would be simpler if each product was linked to one category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a [many-to-many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). You do not need a ProductToCategory-Model.

Instead you need this relation in your ProductCategory-Model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product');
}
```

And one in your Product-Model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ProductCategory');
}
```

You can also specify the name of the pivot-table (the product_to_category-table) and the column names:

```
public function categories()
{
    $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ProductCategory', 'table_name', 'product_id ', 'product_category_id ');
}
```

With this you're able to query it as follows:

```
$linked_products = $category->products()->orderBy('name')->get();
```

Comment: But where is noted that product id 1 belongs to category id 1 and category id 2?

Comment: @AlvinBakker Take a look at my updated answer. Laravel guesses the names based on your model-name. But you are able to specify them explicitly if the columns or table is named differently.

Comment: I have adapted the question with the database layout to show you what I mean why I need the `product_to_categories` table, as one product can be in 3 categories. Your adapted answer is that the categories and products are linked together and just that the naming is different. But that is not the case as there is one in between. Hope the addition of the database layout in my question makes this more clear

Comment: @AlvinBakker thanks for the database schema! This is a many-to-many pivot table schema. You don't need the ProductToCategory-Model but you do need the table of course. Believe me, try it as stated in my answer. It will work as you need it to! Laravel knows many-to-many relations. It is perfectly made for this pivot-schema. You can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: OK, I am getting your answer; Laravel makes these relations automatically. But when I adapt my models with your example, I get this error: `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'spincms.product_product_category' doesn't exist (SQL: select `products`.*, `product_product_category`.`product_category_id` as `pivot_product_category_id`, `product_product_category`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id` from `products` inner join `product_product_category` on `products`.`id` = `product_product_category`.`product_id` where `product_product_category`.`product_category_id` = 1 order by `name` asc)`

Comment: When I rename the product_to_categories table into product_product_category it works. So there is just something wrong with the line `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ProductCategory', 'product_to_categories', 'product_id ', 'product_category_id ');` How do I change this to use table product_to_categories table, as renaming the table is not an option anymore

Comment: OK, you need to specify your table name and column names. So for the Product-Model: `$this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ProductCategory', 'product_to_categories', 'product_id ', 'product_category_id ');` and for the ProductCategory-Model: `$this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product', 'product_to_categories',  'product_category_id ', 'product_id ');`

Comment: Specify the table name (product_to_categories) in both models (see comment above) - just copy both lines.

Comment: Ah. Dumb me :( And in ProductCategories I needed to switch the id column names for it to work. You are awesome. Thanx!

Comment: Glad it helped. Laravel is awesome. Once you've got it, you'll love how easy relations can be.